# Build the architecture for a Flutter App with flutter_bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have to develop a simple app with Flutter and I am trying for the first time the bloc pattern. I am using `flutter_bloc` package but I have two main problems and got stuck:

1. All the screens in the app have blocs that depends on repos to make requests to a server, and for each request I need a token. I obtain the token at the `authentication_bloc` (login), but I can't share that token to all the blocs unless I make them dependent on auth_bloc (the bloc who has the user model storing the token). For a simple app, maybe it works but if other bloc has more bloc dependencies besides the auth_bloc, it could become a mess injecting all the blocs as dependencies. What alternative could be a good solution?
2. For the navigation I have a `bloc` for bottom navigation bar. But I want to all the screens on tabs can call the `change_tab()` function at bottom bar bloc. And again is the same problem, I only can add events at bottom bar bloc if the other blocs have a dependency on bottom bar bloc. I dont want to add the auth bloc and the bottom bar bloc as dependencies on all the blocs that manages all the screens.

I appreciate advices, alternatives or documentation where I can learn to build a good architecture for apps a bit more complex than the examples showed [here](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/gettingstarted)

Comment: I think bloc is not good pattern for complex apps, bloc contains core logic and UI management (state) in the same class, in complex apps we should separate both.
In my app i tried to split in 3 layouts : usecases (reusable core logic, like auth), blocs (dedicated to screen logic, call usecases and interface presenter.display... to notify) and viewmodel (impl presenter and create state streams for widgets).
It's not really bloc pattern but like that logic, state presentation and reusable core logic are correctly separated.
Anyway each app need to find her best architecture, good luck :p

Comment: Well, I used to build my apps with a MVC variant logic, but I read that BLoC is a better option to build more complex apps, so I decided to give it a try. I guess I cant force to all my apps to be built in some architecture xD

Comment: Flutter still really new and there is not unique good architecture, but you can merge your MVC way with bloc pattern, maybe the result can be good.
I think bloc is not enough separated, difficult to test, reusability.. but many others will love this. Transform future callbacks into stream with state is good, but try to separate in multiple layers, i think it will works better.

Answer (score 2):

You can store your token in `Repository` such as `userRepository.persistToken(event.token)` and `await userRepository.deleteToken();`
Repository act like Repository Pattern. You do not need to know data come from cloud or local database 
In example below, userRepository can be app level so all bloc can use it 
full example code https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/examples/flutter_login/lib/authentication/authentication_bloc.dart 
code snippet

```
void main() {
  BlocSupervisor.delegate = SimpleBlocDelegate();
  final userRepository = UserRepository();
  runApp(
    BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
      create: (context) {
        return AuthenticationBloc(userRepository: userRepository)
          ..add(AppStarted());
      },
      child: App(userRepository: userRepository),
    ),
  );
}

...

import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:user_repository/user_repository.dart';

import 'package:flutter_login/authentication/authentication.dart';

class AuthenticationBloc
    extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState> {
  final UserRepository userRepository;

  AuthenticationBloc({@required this.userRepository})
      : assert(userRepository != null);

  @override
  AuthenticationState get initialState => AuthenticationUninitialized();

  @override
  Stream<AuthenticationState> mapEventToState(
    AuthenticationEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is AppStarted) {
      final bool hasToken = await userRepository.hasToken();

      if (hasToken) {
        yield AuthenticationAuthenticated();
      } else {
        yield AuthenticationUnauthenticated();
      }
    }

    if (event is LoggedIn) {
      yield AuthenticationLoading();
      await userRepository.persistToken(event.token);
      yield AuthenticationAuthenticated();
    }

    if (event is LoggedOut) {
      yield AuthenticationLoading();
      await userRepository.deleteToken();
      yield AuthenticationUnauthenticated();
    }
  }
}
```

You can use `MultiBlocProvider` to Wrap yous blocs in app level 
The following example is Map and Position 
https://gitlab.kaleidos.net/piweek/betover/betover-mobile/blob/7b9368288743be602f37014f7a49ed4ef943afc1/lib/main.dart

```
void main() {
  BlocSupervisor.delegate = SimpleBlocDelegate();

  runApp(
    MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<MapBloc>(
          create: (context) => MapBloc(),
        ),
        BlocProvider<PoisBloc>(
          create: (context) => PoisBloc(
            mapBloc: BlocProvider.of<MapBloc>(context),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      child: App(),
    )
  );
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Bet Over',
      theme: appTheme,
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) =>
          MultiBlocProvider(
            providers: [
              BlocProvider<MapBloc>(
                create: (context) => BlocProvider.of<MapBloc>(context),
              ),
              BlocProvider<PoisBloc>(
                create: (context) => BlocProvider.of<PoisBloc>(context),
              ),
            ],
            child: MapPage(),
          ),
        '/create-poi': (context) =>
          MultiBlocProvider(
            providers: [
              BlocProvider<MapBloc>(
                create: (context) => BlocProvider.of<MapBloc>(context),
              ),
              BlocProvider<PoisBloc>(
                create: (context) => BlocProvider.of<PoisBloc>(context),
              ),
            ],
            child: CreatePoimPage(),
          ),
      }
    );
  }
}
```

and use it https://gitlab.kaleidos.net/piweek/betover/betover-mobile/blob/7b9368288743be602f37014f7a49ed4ef943afc1/lib/ui/widgets/map.dart

```
class _MapState extends State<Map> {
  MapBloc _mapBloc;
  PoisBloc _poisBloc;


@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _mapBloc = BlocProvider.of<MapBloc>(context);
    _poisBloc = BlocProvider.of<PoisBloc>(context);

...
    List<Marker> _generateMarkers () {
    if (!(_mapBloc.state is MapViewboxChanged && _poisBloc.state is PoisLoaded))
      return [];
```

Comment: Yes, I've checked the [felangel](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterlogintutorial) documentation, but that cant answer a problem: If I have other blocs that make queries (through repositories) to a REST API using the token, and the token is invalid, the auth_bloc should be notified and yield the "need_auth_state" to reload the login page. But to notify the auth_bloc, all the blocs would have to have a dependency on auth_bloc. I asked the same question on the github of flutter_bloc and they answered me a couple of alternatives, but if you can suggest another, I will appreciate a lot.

Comment: How about use App Level State. example code https://gist.github.com/mcany/2dffd93e20d860d62f83dcd363cc7a31

Comment: Can you please share the link to github where you asked your questions?